# Ubuntu command line./idea.sh can start idea, but the desktop icon clicks to find JDK not found

Tags: java

Ubuntu command line./idea.sh can start idea, but the desktop icon clicks to find JDK not found.

etc/profile  bashrc  and etc/environment has java enviroment.
i'm so doubted...

if i Click the idea icon ...prompt
No JDK found. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

Comment: please check if your JDK_HOME variable is set. (I guess your idea.sh has the variable set). Type the following: 

echo $JDK_HOME

If it comes out empty, ... export JDK_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk/ in your bashrc and restart your session (i.e. logout and log back in).

Comment: Generate a new shortcut from inside IntelliJ

Comment: I tried it, but still can't, echo $JDK_HOME starts to be empty, but after I configure export JDK_HOME in .bashrc, I can see the path. Restart Ubuntu system and click on the idea or prompt the same error, can't find JDK. . . . Uncomfortable

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal,

```
nano /etc/environment
```

Add this variable, and change the path accordingly to the directory where you have your JDK in.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk"
```

And if that doesn't work,
Try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

And select the number of the JDK installation you wish to use for both java and javac

Afterwards, restart your machine

Comment: Nano /etc/environment
This command has no effect, I tried it a few times, and the restart is useless.
I did not install open-jdk, the installation is jdk1.8_181 version, use sudo update-alternatives --config java this command, prompt me:
Update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
But I type java-version to have output.
Java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)